# Images are being uploaded on Cloudinary but not displaying in my React App

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, error-handling, cloudinary

I'm working on a React gallery app and I have uploaded images to Cloudinary using NodeJs but I have been unable to access them from my account to display them in the gallery app. In my console, I keep getting an error message and a broken image icon. I tried a couple different ways to write the route in the myImage variable with the following codes but no change.

```
const myImage = cld.image('publicid.<ext>');

const myImage = cld.image('folder/publicid.<ext>');
```

//Any ideas on how I can fix this is greatly appreciated. I have included a picture of the error message and the current display of my app

```
import React from 'react';
import { AdvancedImage } from '@cloudinary/react';
import { Cloudinary } from '@cloudinary/url-gen';
import { fill } from "@cloudinary/url-gen/actions/resize";



const Home =()=>{
const cld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
        cloudName: 'demo',  //Your account Cloudinary_Name  
    }
});

const myImage = cld.image('public_id');

myImage.resize(fill().width(300).height(200));

  return(
     <div>
      <AdvancedImage  cldImg= {myImage} />
      </div>
  )

};

 export default Home;
```

[image]

Comment: the `public_id` of your image is `public_id` where you should put the `public_id` of one of your image. You can try `sample` or `South%20Korea_Image%20Gallery/lvi6kgfocamcggp4soeg` which is an image in your account. Also, make sure that the cloud is set to `diarrmhtt` and not `demo`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `demo` as your cloudName? If so please change the cloudName to the one in your cloudinary dashboard.

For debugging purposes would you mind console logging what the image variable returns and sharing the results for further assistance?